# Access microsoft outlook in web

Tags: asp.net, outlook

I am using asp.net. Can anybody say how do I access my Microsoft Outlook through a web application. If this is possible please explain in detail.

Thanks in advance
Regards,
s.venkatesh.

Comment: Have you tried Outlook Web Access?  It's a Microsoft product designed specifically for that purpose:  http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/code/OWA/index.html.  Or do you mean access it programmatically in some way for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps trying to contact an Exchange server rather than an individual mail client? If so, have of [Using .NET and WebDAV to access an Exchange server](http://blog.mbcharbonneau.com/2006/10/26/using-net-and-webdav-to-access-an-exchange-server/).